How to Mix Image and Fabric Textures on a 3D Model in Blender?
I'm working on a 3D model in Blender and I have already applied an image texture to it. Now, I also want to apply a fabric texture on top of the image texture in such a way that both textures are mixed together, with the fabric texture overlaying the image texture.
How can I achieve this effect? What nodes or steps should I use in the Shader Editor to blend these two textures effectively?

You could use a Color > Mix Color node to mix the 2 Image Texture nodes but maybe show your Shader Editor and 3D view?
